# Getting a wrong output using arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, design-patterns

The challenge is to find a number whose individual digits multiplied by consecutively increasing power and added up, equal the initial number.

Eg: take 89, split it into 8 and 9, then `8^1 + 9^2 = 89`

```java
static List<Integer> sumDigPow(int a, int b) { 
        List<Integer> eureka = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
        List<String> digits = new ArrayList<String>();
        String num;
        int sum = 0, multi;

    for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
        num = String.valueOf(i);
        digits.add(num);

        for (int j=0; j<digits.size(); j++) {
                multi = (int)Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(digits.get(j)), j+1);
                sum += multi;
        }

        if (sum == i) eureka.add(i);

        sum = 0;
        digits.clear();
    }

    return eureka;
}
```

With an input of 1 and 100 (the range), the output should be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 89], but I'm getting all of the numbers [1, 2 ... 100].

I've started learning java fairly recently and can't seem to find the issue in the code. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
static List<Integer> sumDigPow(int a, int b) {
    List<Integer> eureka = new ArrayList<Integer>(0);
    String num;
    int sum = 0, multi;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        num = String.valueOf(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < num.length(); j++) {
            multi = (int) Math.pow(Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(j)), j + 1);
            sum += multi;
        }

        if (sum == i) {
            eureka.add(i);
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
    return eureka;
}
```

Explanation:

1. You were not checking the second digit of the number.
2. Loop over each character of the *String* `num`.
3. There is no need of the `digits` arraylist, you can just use the *numeric* value of the char.

Answer (score 4):

The problem were those lines :

```
num = String.valueOf(i);
digits.add(num);
```

You did not split your number into digits. You were just putting your whole numbers into `digits` list. Look at this code :

```
static List<Integer> sumDigPow(int a, int b) {
        List<Integer> eureka = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> digits;
        String num;
        int sum = 0, multi;

        for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
            num = String.valueOf(i);
            digits = Arrays.asList(num.split(""));

            for (int j = 0; j < digits.size(); j++) {
                multi = (int) Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(digits.get(j)), j + 1);
                sum += multi;
            }

            if (sum == i) eureka.add(i);

            sum = 0;
        }

        return eureka;
    }
```

I simply split your string number into digits using `Arrays.asList(num.split(""))`. It outputs for `a=1`, `b=100` the list :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
89
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I used an arraylist to store the digits solely to use the .clear() method but I see it's not necessary.

Comment: There are more optimizations that could be made but I tried not to modify your code that much :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `char[]` to split the numbers into digits as an array of characters (you are just adding the **whole** number as a single string to the list, not its individual digits):

```
...
    char[] digits;
...
    digits = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
```

Then if you subtract `'0'` from each `char` digit you automatically get the actual `int` value of the digit without having to invoke the `Integer.parseInt` method on a String, or any other parsing method:

```
    (int)Math.pow(digits[j] - '0', j + 1);
```

The full code would look like this:

```
static List<Integer> sumDigPow(int a, int b) {
    List<Integer> eureka = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int sum = 0;
    char[] digits;

    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        digits = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < num.length(); j++) 
            sum += (int)Math.pow(digits[j] - '0', j + 1);

        if (sum == i) eureka.add(i);
        sum = 0;
    }
    return eureka;
}
```